# Bootstrapping in lazy loaded Modules

Tags: angular

The official [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-bootstrap-array) says:
"*Among other things, the bootstrapping process creates the component(s) listed in the bootstrap array and inserts each one into the browser DOM.*"

But it appears to me that I can't bootstrap components in my lazy loaded feature modules. When I route a specific url my feature module get's loaded (constructor is called) but the component defined in the `bootstrap: [MyComponent]` is neither rendered nor is the constructor or the ngOnInit function called. Am I doing something wrong?

---

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
```

***dashboard.module.ts***

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';    
import { Dashboard } from './dashboard.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
 CommonModule
    DashboardRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log("DashboardModule loaded");
  }
}
```

***dashboard.component.ts***

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  styles: [],
  template: `
    foo bar
  `,
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    console.log("TestComponent construct");
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("TestComponent init");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you need a bootstrap attributes for your lazy loaded modules. The routing of the lazy loaded module will determine which component to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use entryComponents array to achieve the same thing..
more information is [here](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components)

```
entryComponents: [
    DashboardComponent
],
```

Answer (score -2):

TestComponent

> dashboard.component.ts